# Unable to make the foreign key with non-primary key

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a database called **Donation** within it it got this column **IC** its is and identity number value so I had already set it into `IsUnique` but somehow it still return the error message

> Donation_Customers_Target_Donation_Customers_Source: : The types of all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be the same as the corresponding property types in the Principal Role. The type of property 'IC' on entity 'Donation' does not match the type of property 'CustomerID' on entity 'Customers' in the referential constraint 'Donation_Customers'.

And here is the model of the **Donation** and **Customers**
Customer

```
[Key]
public int CustomerID { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "IC")]
[Index(IsUnique = true)]
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "IC is required")]
[MinLength(14)][MaxLength(14)]
public string IC { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "First Name")]
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "First name required")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

Donation

```
[Key]
public int DonationId { get; set; }
public DateTime? TransacTime { get; set; }
public int Amount { get; set; }

public string IC { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("IC")]
public Customers Customers { get; set; }
```

Comment: What version of EF?  EF6 would require you to declare IC as the Key of Customer.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Is EF6. Is thre any way to do that by using a non-primary key as foreign key or it is impossible.

Comment: You can use either key as the Entity Key.  EF doesn’t care which one.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft to set **IC** as Foreign Key but it return the **IC** is not a primary for the table

Comment: In EF6 an entity can only have one Key.  So switch the [Key] attribute to IC.  In the SQL Server the foreign key can reference a unique index.